# ActiveWeb controller : testing headers values presence

Tags: activeweb

I tried to test the presence of `Authorization` value in the request header and my `AuthorizationFilter` has never been hit:

```
@Test
public void shouldContainAuthorizationHeader() {
    request().params("invoiceNumber","988665646546457").get("findByInvoiceNumber");
    a(statusCode()).shouldBeEqual(403);
}
```

Here is the filter declaration:

```
public class AppControllerConfig extends AbstractControllerConfig {

    public void init(AppContext context) {
        add(new DBConnectionFilter(), new CatchAllFilter()).to(AuthorsController.class, InterventionsController.class);
        add(new AuthorizationFilter()).to(InterventionsController.class);
    }
}
```

Here is its implementation:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends HttpSupportFilter {

    private final static String EMPTY_STRING_SEPARATOR = " ";

    @Override
    public void before() {

        if (!controllerProtected()) {
            return;// allow to fall to controller
        }

        if (!hasAuthorizationHeader() && controllerProtected()) {
            render("/errors/message", map("message", "Access denied", "code", 403));
        }
    }
```

`Protected` interface is the same as in [activeweb-secure](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-secure/blob/master/src/main/java/app/controllers/authorization/Protected.java) example.

The `InterventionsController` is annotated with `@Protected`:

```
@Protected
public class InterventionsController extends APIController {
...
}
```

I tried to extend my test class from AppIntegrationSpec:

```
public class InterventionsControllerIntegrationTest extends AppIntegrationSpec {
...
}
```

but in this case `request` method is no more accessible.

Is it a normal behaviour ? If so, how to test different headers values ?
I'm using the latest`2.3-SNAPSHOT` version of activeweb.

Thank you.

Comment: I finished with the following implementation of test: `controller("/api/v2/interventions").params("invoiceNumber", "1234567").get("findByInvoiceNumber");`. Then `a(statusCode()).shouldBeEqual(403);` But the response status was `200`.

Comment: What is the more correct way to go to test such a kind of things, taking into account that all the protected controllers have the same stuff to test in their headers and I'd like to DRY it if possible.

Comment: As for status code testing, I figured out the value to test. I'm using ` errors` view displaying `message` and `code` values as JSON. So when testing `a(val("code")).shouldBeEqual(403);`, it passed.